# JSP jQuery не работает автокомплит

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jsp

Подключаю автокомплит из jQuery-UI следующим образом:

```
$("#country").autocomplete({
          source:  "getdata.jsp"
     });
```

Getdata.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
    out.println("Russia");
    out.println("Nigeria");
    out.println("Usa");
%>
```

И ничего не работает. В хроме видно, что запрос отправляется, ответ приходит, но в подсказках ничего не выводится. Если в качестве source использовать массив, то все хорошо.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ должен приходить в виде JSON-массива. Из документации к autocomplete [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):

> String: When a string is used, the
> Autocomplete plugin expects that
> string to point to a URL resource that
> will return JSON data.

Отдавайте с помощью JSP JSON-массив и всё будет работать. Как это сделать - не знаю, т.к. не программирую на JSP. Но беглое гугление даёт тысячи [адекватных результатов](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/creating-parsing-json-data-with-java-servlet-struts-jsp-json/).

Comment: Спасибо. Никогда не работал с JSON. Какой вид должен быть у ответа?

Comment: Все, разобрался)

Comment: Это обычное представление объектов/массивов в виде строки. Ответ должен быть таким: `["Russia","Nigeria","USA"]`. Желательное еще правильный MIME-type отдавать ("application/json").

Comment: Именно в jQuery нужен массив или json в виде ключ-значение. Просто с массивом не работает у меня, или я его не правильно возвращаю.

Comment: А покажите, что возвращается?

Comment: Все заработало) Я просто использовал JSONObject вместо JSONArray. Спасибо за помощь.